# Mapping a path to a domain on a local server

Tags: dns, localhost

I am hosting a local web server for testing using EasyPHP, but I want to map a path to a local domain. For example, `c:/www/Blog` to `blog.app` or `c:/www/CMS` to `cms.app`.

I have tried searching on Google but it says use ngix or a WordPress wiki link. Can I do it with the Windows host file or do I need to get some new software?

OK, so what do i need to but in the vhosts file and in the windows hosts file. in the vhosts file i have copyed and pasted the sample code for all my directorys by what do i need to put for the server name and the the sever alias. Also what do i put in the windows hosts file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the EasyPHP "bundle" uses the Apache web server... in which case you need to either update httpd.conf (the main server config) and set the DocumentRoot and ServerName directives to the appropriate path and domain name, or set up a VirtualHost (preferred) in httpd-vhosts.conf, which will enable you to set up multiple sites. Restart Apache after making changes to the config files.

Use the Windows HOSTS file (effectively local DNS) to direct the domain name to the IP address of your web server.